# Peskin and Schroeder's QFT eq. (7.88)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices, dimensional-regularization

On Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book, page 251, the book discussed how things will be changed in $d$ dimensions. For example $g_{\mu \nu}g^{\mu \nu}=d$.

In eq. (7.88), the book gave how Dirac matrices can be manipulated as a set of $d$ matrices:
$$\{\gamma^{\mu} ,\gamma^{\nu}\}=2g^{\mu \nu}, \ \ \ \ \ tr[1]=4 \tag{7.88}$$
How to understand $tr[1]=4$? is this "$1$" identity matrix? why not $tr[1]=d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $d=2N$, and in $d=2N+1$, dimensions the trace of the gamma-matrix space identity matrix is ${\rm tr}({\mathbb I}_{\rm spinors})$ is $2^N$.

Comment: Do you have any insight into why this is the case?

Comment: You need to read up on the representation theory of gamma matrices. Perhaps here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices. The basic idea is that you can use a set of $N$ fermion creation opertors to obtain the $\gamma$'s and these span a $2^N$ Fock space